# Prevent view controller from stacking IOS 13 (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios13

I am working on an app and recently updated to my Xcode. With this update the way view controllers are presented is changed and I want to revert it back to its old ways. They used to display over the other ones but now they "stack".

I would like the iPhone on the left, while what I currently have is the iPhone on the right. 
[image]Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change presented view controller modalPresentationStyle to full screen.

```
let myModalController = MyModalController()
myModalController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
self.present(myModalController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```